# Can you change basis in an exterior algebra?

Tags: mathematical-physics, fourier-transform, exterior-algebra, change-of-basis

Consider the inverse Fourier transform

$\mathbf f(x)=\int\frac{dk}{2\pi}\mathbf{\hat f}(k)e^{ik\cdot x}$

where $\{x,k\}\subset\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbf{\hat f}$ ([a (0, -1) Fourier transform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransform.html)) is valued in degree-1 elements of the [exterior algebra](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExteriorAlgebra.html) of the complex free vector space of $\mathbb R$, $\mathbf{\hat f}:\mathbb R\to \Lambda^1 \mathbb{C}^\mathbb{R}$, with generating elements of $\Lambda\,\mathbb{C}^\mathbb{R}$ are notated $\theta_{k}$.  Importantly, restrict $\mathbf{\hat f}$ to the form $\mathbf{\hat f}(k)=\hat{f}(k)\theta_{k}$ for any $\hat{f}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$.

Now, the product of two independent, single-mode functions $\mathbf{f}'(x)$ and $\mathbf{f}''(x)$ (k-space deltas, where $\mathbf{\hat f}'(k)=\delta(k-k')\theta_{k}$ and $\mathbf{\hat f}''(k)=\delta(k-k'')\theta_{k}$ for some $k'\ne k''$) is a non-zero 2-vector proportional to $\theta_{k'}\theta_{k''}$.

**Question:** What about the product of two x-space deltas (where $\mathbf{\hat f}'(k)=e^{ik\cdot x'}\theta_{k}$ and $\mathbf{\hat f}''(k)=e^{ik\cdot x''}\theta_{k}$)?  Does the Fourier transform change basis to yield a non-zero 2-vector proportional to $\theta_{x'}\theta_{x''}$?  (Taking a linear combination of $\theta_{k}$ to a linear combination of $\theta_{x}$?)  A change of basis seems possible for a finite-dimensional exterior algebra (e.g. $\Lambda\,\mathbb{R}^3$), at the very least.

Or do $\mathbf{f}'$ & $\mathbf{f}''$ pick up enough $\theta_k$ such that $\mathbf{f}'(x)\cdot\mathbf{f}''(x)=0$ everywhere?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to ask whether the isometric isomorphism $L^2(A)\simeq L^2(A_{\wedge})$ ($A$ a locally compact abelian group, $A_{\wedge}$ its character group) lifts to an isometric isomorphism $\bigwedge^{n}L^2(A)\simeq \bigwedge^{n}L^2(A_{\wedge})$ of exterior powers?

In physics-speak, that would be something like "the equivalence between the position-space and momentum-space decompositions of a one-particle wavefunction determines an equivalence between such decompositions of $n$-particle antisymmetric wavefunctions."

Comment: I think so.  Does $L^2(A)\simeq L^2(A_\wedge)$ lift to $\bigwedge^n L^2(A)\simeq \bigwedge^n L^2(A_\wedge)$ ?

Comment: Some problems with the way you have written what you have written: 1. $\mathbf{f}$ is not defined, as $\mathbf{\hat f}$ is not necessarily integrable (if it takes on values in infinitely many vectors you will have this trouble). 2. $\delta(k-k')\theta_k$ is not a function $\Bbb R^n \to \Lambda^1\Bbb C^{\Bbb R}$. At best it is a distribution on $F(\Bbb R, \Lambda\Bbb C^{\Bbb R})$, where $F(X,Y)$ is the space of arbitrary functions $X\to Y$. This space is total garbage, however. At least you should look at a kind of schwartz space $\mathcal S(\Bbb R, \Lambda\Bbb C^{\Bbb R})$,  ...

Comment: ... but unless you can give the target a topology this space doesn't make sense. Finally, going off your definitions, what should $e^{ik x'}\theta_k \cdot e^{ik x''}\theta_k$ be? Either $e^{ik(x'+x'')} \theta_k \wedge\theta_k =0 $ or $e^{ik(x'+x'')}\theta_k\otimes \theta_k$. Both these answers seem unsatisfactory. But it is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve or what context you have, so I have to go off your definitions, which I believe to be very poor.

Comment: My mistake, I forget that SE views helpfulness, pedagogy, and "trying to see what a user meant to ask" about as highly as cats view bubble baths.

Comment: You may assume $\mathbf{f}$ is defined and restrict $\hat f$ as appropriate.  $\theta_{k'}\theta_{k''}$ is denoted a [2-vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivector), thus an exterior product.  In the question's context, $\mathbf{f}$ is a field eigenstate in QFT, and its domain $\mathbb{R}^d$ is assumed to be the well-defined limit of the cyclic lattice $\mathbf x\equiv a\mathbf n, \mathbf n\in \mathbb{Z}^d_N$ as $(a,N)\to(0,\infty)$; I used $d=1$ for simplicity.